# Angular Material Nav Bar Set Default Active Item

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, navbar, angular-material

I am experimenting with an angular app using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and cannot seem to get my navbar to set the default item to be selected. I am using the [Angular Material Navbar](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/navBar) ([Directive Info](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdNavBar)) for displaying my views and here is my template html for the navbar:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<md-content class="md-padding">
  <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
    <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="layout.home" name="home">Home</md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="layout.gallery" name="gallery">Gallery</md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="#" name="page3">Page Three</md-nav-item>
  </md-nav-bar>
</md-content>
```

In my controller, I am setting up the currentNavItem to 'home' which should correspond to my md-nav-item named home which I felt should set it to be selected based on `md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem"`

```
export default class HeaderController {
  constructor($log) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      $log,
    });
    this.currentNavItem = 'home';
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.$log.debug('HeaderController.$onInit');
    this.$log.debug(this.currentNavItem);
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as to why this doesn't make my list item selected by default when I load the app.

**Edit**

The issue in my case was that my controller was not being used in the navbar selection `md-selected-nav-item="$ctrl.currentNavItem"'. Adding values for each md-nav-item didn't seem to affect the active item setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `value` attribute of each `md-nav-item` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Kgdvgd?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="vm.currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="layout.home" name="home" value="home">Home</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="layout.gallery" name="gallery" value="gallery">Gallery</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="#" name="page3" value ="page3">Page Three</md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

js

```
angular
    .module
    (
        'MyApp',
        ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']
    )
    .controller
    (
        'AppCtrl',
        function()
        {
            this.currentNavItem = "home";
        }
    );
```

Comment: I updated my code and also noticed that I was missing my controller syntax for `md-selected-nav-item="$ctrl.currentNavItem"` which after changing seemed to work however for some reason the active item styling isn't rendering properly. Maybe a caching issue? I'm not providing any css anywhere for the header. I'll update my original post with what I'm getting rendered.

Comment: @user3786596 I think I answered your original question. Perhaps it's better to create another question regarding the styling issue, for future readers.

Comment: 'value' is not a recognized attribute for md-nav-item

Comment: @ricka use the name attribute instead. Not sure if it changed but it should be name attribute not value

Comment: "Value attribute is not allowed here" and does nothing